# Animation on elements only applies on the first render for flastlist component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to animate **newly** elements that are added to my `messages` array with my  translateYChatBubble``` animation. However, whenever I add an element to the array, the element doesn't animate, it only applies on the first render.

Here is my flatlist component render item:

```
  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <ChatBubble
        key={index}
        message={item.message.trim()}
        index={index}
        animate={true}
      />
    );
  };
```

Here's a portion of my `ChatBubble` component:

```
const translateYChatBubble = useRef(new Animated.Value(20)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(translateYChatBubble, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, []);

return (
 <Container
      style={{
        alignItems: isMe ? "flex-end" : "flex-start",
        marginTop: addMargin ? 25 : 0,
        transform: [{ translateY: translateYChatBubble }],
      }}
    >
      {children}

    </Container>
```

My goal is to have the function animate elements whenever they are added to the array, but they're only animating on the first render.